# Impossible to invoke a method on array. How to merge multiple objects and keep as objects

Tags: templating, array

```
{% set newsletterImages = newsletter.imagesCongratulations|merge(newsletter.imagesCis)|merge(newsletter.imagesSection3) %}
{% set transformedImages = newsletterImages %}

{% for image in newsletterImages %}
  {{ image.title }}<br />

{% endfor %}
```

newsletterImages is merging images from 3 different global fields.
I want to then randomise and only output 6 of these images.

However, when I try

```
{% set transformedImages = newsletterImages.orderBy('RAND()').limit(6) %}
```

I get the error: Impossible to invoke a method ("orderBy") on an array. and Impossible to invoke a method ("limit") on an array.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with Craft's [`shuffle()` method](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/templating/functions.html#shuffle-array) and Twig's [slice filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/slice.html) (like you mentioned in your answer).

```
{% set newsletterImages = newsletter.imagesCongratulations.all() %}
{% set newsletterImages = newsletterImages | merge(newsletter.imagesCis.all()) %}
{% set newsletterImages = newsletterImages | merge(newsletter.imagesSection3.all()) %}

{% set shuffledImages = shuffle(newsletterImages) %}  // Shuffle our "master" array

{% for image in shuffledImages[:6] %}  // Get the first 6 images
  {{ image.title }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Jalen. Just saw this after I updated my answer. 
But I prefer your naming approach :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete code that achieves what I want. 
In case it is useful to anyone else.

```
{% set newsletterImages = newsletter.imagesCongratulations.all() %}
{% set newsletterImages = newsletterImages | merge(newsletter.imagesCis.all()) %}
{% set newsletterImages = newsletterImages | merge(newsletter.imagesSection3.all()) %}

{% set shuffledImages = shuffle(newsletterImages) %}

{% set transformedImages = [] %}

{% for image in shuffledImages[:6] %}
  {% set transformedImage = craft.imager.transformImage(image, imageTransformParams) %}
  {% set transformedImages = transformedImages|merge([transformedImage]) %}
{% endfor %}
```